# How to make a custom requirement card like Volere's?

Tags: boxes

I need to create a simplier version of the Volere's Requirement card. Here it is:

[image]

Since I only know the very basics of LaTeX, I don't know how to create a template for this from scratch. My idea was to make this like:

```
\begin{requirement}
   \number 75
   \type 9
   \description ...
\end{}
```

I don't even know if this is possible or not...

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

What I've got so far:

```
\newenvironment{requirement}[5]{
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l p{7cm} p{4cm}|}
\hline
\# #1            &     & Type: #2 \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space Event: #3 \newline    \\ 
Description:   & \multicolumn{2}{p{11cm}|}{#4 \newline} \\ 
Fit Criterion: & \multicolumn{2}{p{11cm}|}{#5 \newline} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
{}
```

The call of the environment:

```
\begin{requirement}{1}{2}{3}{Test}{Test}
\end{requirement}
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Your question is very broad;. Where do you have the problems specifically? Creating the environment, or the box?"

Comment: @Johannes_B I don't know where to start making this, I don't have anything yet. Has I said, I know very little about TeX :(

Comment: The desired output could be achieved based upon a customized description environment or, with a slighly different alignment, based on a tabular.

Comment: @leandriis I was hoping that I could achieve it by coding a new environment. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, you can definitely "hide" the description or tabular environment behind a newly defined environment. If I have some time later, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @leandriis I have this so far: https://pastebin.com/wszwaRsX (and the result for that http://prntscr.com/pucwvm). One problem I noticed with that is that I begin and end my environment without come text between... Is it a normal thing to do?

Comment: @Bishop19: Could you please add the code and the screenshot of the result directly into yout question? (you can use the edit button below your question to do so.)

Comment: @leandriis done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, the following that is based on `enumitem`'s `description`, `multicols` and `tcolorbox` might serve as a place to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{myreq}[1]{%
\setlist[description]{font=\normalfont\color{darkgray}}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=black,colback=white, sharp corners, boxrule=1pt]%
\bfseries\color{blue}%
\begin{description}#1}%
{\end{description}\end{tcolorbox}}

\newcommand{\threeinline}[3]{\begin{multicols}{3}#1 #2 #3\end{multicols}}
\newcommand{\twoinline}[2]{\begin{multicols}{2}#1 #2\end{multicols}}

\newcommand{\reqno}{\item[Requirement \#:]}
\newcommand{\reqtype}{\item[Requirement Type:]}
\newcommand{\reqevent}{\item[Event/BUC/PUC \#:]}
\newcommand{\reqdesc}{\item[Description:]}
\newcommand{\reqrat}{\item[Rationale:]}
\newcommand{\reqorig}{\item[Originator:]}
\newcommand{\reqfit}{\item[Fit Criterion:]}
\newcommand{\reqsatis}{\item[Customer Satisfaction:]}
\newcommand{\reqdissat}{\item[Customer Dissatisfaction:]}
\newcommand{\reqdep}{\item[Dependencies:]}
\newcommand{\reqconf}{\item[Conflicts:]}
\newcommand{\reqmater}{\item[Materials:]}
\newcommand{\reqhist}{\item[History:]}

\begin{document}
\begin{myreq}
  \threeinline
    {\reqno 75}
    {\reqtype 9}
    {\reqevent 7.9}
  \reqdesc description text description text description text 
  \reqrat some more text some more text some more text 
  \reqorig other text other text other text 
  \reqfit longer text that needs more than one line longer text that needs more than one line
  \twoinline
    {\reqsatis 5}
    {\reqdissat 3}
  \twoinline
  {\reqdep some more text}
  {\reqconf 111}
  \reqmater other text other text other text 
  \reqhist other text other text other text 
\end{myreq}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! That's perfect!